# How to prove a system is stable if the characteristic equation have non zero positive coefficients?

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, stability

I read that a control system would be stable if its characteristic equation has got all the terms present and are positive. But I could not find any proof to it. How does one prove it?

Comment: Where did you read that? Also would \$ s^3+s^2+s+10=0 \$ be a "characteristic equation [that] has got all the terms present and are positive"? Because it has eigenvalues $$0.68251 + 1.93971i \\
   0.68251 - 1.93971i \\
  -2.36502 + 0.00000i$$

Comment: It's not a text book, but a lecture not given by a professor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very likely a reference to [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs). Seems like the statement in the original question should only apply when a polynomial has exclusively real roots. The original statement was already disproven by @jDAQ with a counter-example, where \$s^3+s^2+s+10\$ has two roots with positive real parts, even though all coefficients are positive.

Applying Descartes' rule to \$s^3+s^2+s+10\$, we should first see the number of coefficient sign changes (0) and draw the conclusion the polynomial "has 0 positive real roots", which is true (it has 2 right-hand-side complex roots instead). By inverting the sign of odd-powered terms, we then see 3 sign transitions, leading to the conclusion the polynomial "has 3 or 1 negative real roots". Therefore, Descartes' rule gives us two possible predictions on the roots:

1. \$s^3+s^2+s+10\$ has 3 negative real roots (incorrect prediction)
2. \$s^3+s^2+s+10\$ has 1 negative real root and two complex roots (correct prediction)

The first prediction would be confirmed for a polynomial such as \$s^3+10s^2+10s+1\$. It has the same coefficient signs as the counter-example and has 3 negative real roots (\$-1\$, \$-8.89\$ and \$-0.11\$).

In summary, the original statement from the question

> I read that a control system would be stable if its characteristic equation has got all the terms present and are positive.

only applies in full to polynomials with real roots, since counter-examples with complex roots can be found, as already predicted in Descartes' rule of signs.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!